# Add the same content on page #P when (P-1)%n = 0

Tags: formatting, header-footer

I would like to add the same material in a document with the following constraints.

1. The material is a table with some information.
2. Giving an integer n, the material will only appear on page P such that (P-1)%n = 0. For example, if n = 2 then the material appears on pages 1, 3, 5,... and if n = 4 then the material appears on pages 1, 5, 9,...
3. The material "pushes" the content below him.

Why ? In my tests, I would like to add materials where the students will write their names.

Here are pictures showing the feature wanted.

---

[image]

---

In this case, the title is the beginning of the content.

---

[image]

---

Here "Bla, bla, bla" comes from the standard content managed by LaTeX.

***Technically, I think that a solution should be to change the geometry of the pages P such that (P-1)%n = 0 and to play with absolute positioning for adding the materials but I don't know how to do that.***

I give the following "empty" file as a start.

```
\documentclass[a4,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{ucs}
    \usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\lipsum

\lipsum

\lipsum

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: doesn't the "write your name" box always come above some fixed thing like the start of the section? or do you mean you insert it every other page even in running text with automatic page breaks (which must be possible, but sounds so odd I thought I'd ask for confirmation:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes I am looking for the odd version. Indeed if you think of a test on which the students have to write some answers, this is not so odd. ;-)

Comment: well it's your test so whether I think it odd or not doesn't really matter but you make the student write their name every other page?, seems very odd to me. ? If I was implementing this I'd probably implement this as a top float that only gets positioned on odd pages and doesn't clear the float list when it is positioned so it keeps coming back. possibly not today though.

Comment: You are totally right. Technically the question remains interesting but indeed I was looking toward the wrong direction...

Answer (score 1):

## For the special case of n=2

In this case the `fancyhdr` package might be a solution. It offers the possibility to easily define alternating headers for even and odd pages:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\fbox{\textbf{Name:\hspace*{7cm}Class:\hspace{3.92cm}}}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headheight}{16.09pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\lipsum

\lipsum

\lipsum

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Caveat: your requirement no.3 about pushing the content below is not fulfilled, instead the header is inserted above the text.

Comment: Thanks but I already used the headers for some informations about my tests.

Comment: @projetmbc In this case you could simply add this to your header.